# "this" not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I've been struggling with this for an hour now, and I can't solve it. I'm new to use `this` on javascript, but this is really simple, and it's just not working.

Here's the HTML

```
<ul class="nav pull-right nav-tabs" id="primarynav">
    <li class=" navlink">
        <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navlink active">
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navlink">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navlink").click(function(){
        $(".navlink").removeClass("active");
        this.addClass("active");
    });
});
```

So it **should** remove class `active` from all elements with class `navlink`, and then add class `active` to the clicked element. But it doesn't.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tckf7/

Comment: Keep your browser's developer console open during development, and read the errors it gives you.

Comment: The bad side about keeping it open is that it will take about 30% of my screen height. @thesystem

Comment: They can usually be detached.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change it to:

```
$(this).addClass("active");
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mHeLf/)**

`.addClass()` is a jQuery method and you had been trying to apply it to a non-jQuery object (`this` vs `$(this)`).

Comment: This stops short of an explanation to why `$(this)` works when `this` doesn't. New javascripters often have trouble here, especially with jQuery because the `$` makes things seem mysterious and magical.

Answer (score 2):

[**addClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) is a jQuery method but `this` is just the direct reference to the DOM object. You need to wrap `this` into a jQuery object first before you can use a jQuery method on it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navlink").click(function(){
        $(".navlink").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tckf7/4/) - Using `$(this).addClass()` instead of `this.addClass()`

---

**Edit**

To elaborate a little on this. You can never call jQuery's `addClass()` method on a JavaScript object as `addClass()` is a jQuery method.

To do the same in pure JavaScript, if you want to just use `this`, you could use [**element.className**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.className), similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navlink").click(function(){       
        $(".navlink").removeClass("active");

        //$(this).addClass("active");
        this.className += " active";
    });
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tckf7/5/) - Using `this.className` example

---

Though if you are using jQuery already it would make little sense not to use `$(this).addClass()` instead.

Comment: So, if I would target the element with `getElementById` instead, I could use `this`?

Comment: @Christian: The `addClass()` method will only ever work when called on a jQuery object as it is a jQuery method.

Comment: @Christian: for the sake of completeness I did add some information on how one might use `this` and pure JavaScript but as mentioned, you are already using jQuery so `$(this).addClass()` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

`this` refers to the DOMElement to which jQuery has attached the event. To turn it into a jQuery collection and be able to use jQuery methods like `addClass`, pass it as an argument to `$`:

```
$(this).addClass("active");
```

Inside functions, the `this` keyword actually refers to the context of the function. In the case of event handlers, the context is the DOMElement that the handler is attached to.

Comment: So to use it just with `this` I should do `var this = "$(this);`?

Comment: `this` is a special keyword, so you should not try to reassign it. Rather, to store the jQuery collection, use a variable like `var jQThis = $(this);`

Comment: @Christian: One common convention I have seen and used occasionally  for caching jQuery objects are `var $this = $(this)` for example where the `$` is a Hungarian notation logic indicating this variable holds a jQuery object. Though caching is pointless of `this` if you are only using it once within the current scope.

Answer (score 1):

`this` isn't a jQuery object, use `$(this)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should use $(this)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navlink").click(function(){
        $(".navlink").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tckf7/2/